# Debugging Python program doesn't work after updating to VS Code 1.66.0

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Today (2022/3/31) I let the auto-update function update my `VS Code` to latest version 1.66.0 on `Windows`. After that, my normal debugging process doesn't work any more: when I press F5, the debugging control panel flashes and disappears immediately, nothing else happends. I couldn't find any useful error message on output and terminal windows. My `launch.json` file looks like this:

```
{
        "name": "DEBUG",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\starting.py",        
        "console": "integratedTerminal",    
        "justMyCode": false,
    }
```

I tried to change the `console` above to `externalTerminal` but it didn't help. Could someone  tell me how to find out what's going on here?

Cheers,

Comment: what's going on is not to auto-update next time

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem, could you modify the `program`  to `"program": "${file}",` and open a simple python file to take a debugging?

Comment: You can install the early version of VSCode from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_65). And the python extension had updated yesterday, it maybe has contributed to the problem too.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT I did install a previous version of VSCode but it didn't help. And I think this problem is not caused by new version of `VSCode ` but the new version of `Python extension` (it shows version number `v2022.4.0` and release date is 30 March 2022). After I uninstalled the latest version of VSCode and clear everything in `%appdata` and `%userprofile` (so a clean uninstallation), I installed old version of VSCode and reinstalled python extension. When I tried to debug my python file, a warning appeared saying the setting of `python.pythonPath` is not used anymore  and I should remove it

Comment: @Steven-MSFT I did remove it in `settings.json` and now it starts to run the debug launcher. The inconvenient things are, 1) this warning never showed after I updated the VSCode itself in the first place so I had no clue. 2) unlike VSCode itself, it is not easy to install an older version of extension.

Comment: @tete Install an older version of the extension is very easily. Click the gear button on the bottom-right then select `Install Another Version`.

Comment: @tete Could you update the VSCode to the latest version to have a test again? If it still does not work, then you install the older version of Python extension to make a test.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT sure I can give it a try. I'll update later. Thank you for letting me know how to install older version of extension. About 1 or 2 months ago, after I updated VSCode, another problem started to happen (it showed "Timed out waiting for debuggee to spawn"). And when I tried to google how to roll back I got a wrong impression that it was not easy to do it for extensions.

Comment: ＠tete haha, and thanks for your response.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT I updated VSCode to `1.66.0` and `Python extension` is of version `2022.4.0`. The setting `python.pythonPath` had been removed and now it is working. Thank you! Also you can post an answer so it is easier for others to see how to solve it?

Comment: @tete Hi friend, could you accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to reinstall the Python extension or install the older version of the Python extension. Delete the deprecated configuration of `python.pythonPath` in your settings.json.

Comment: this is happening again in 2024.  trying to debug does nothing after a few runs..no output in console, no info in debug pane..just doesnt seem to run at all.  After to restart vscode each time to get it going again.

Answer (score 5):

Click on the python extention (publisher microsoft) and select "install pre-release". It would be V2022.5.10961002 (you can see it when you hover with the mouse above the extension)

Fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

After digging and digging I've found the issue was with the current version of the python extension for the VS code (mine was the latest).
Downgrading the extension version to v2021.12.1559732655 solved the issue and now breakpoints works.

In order to downgrade the extension go to file->preferences->extension
select the python package
press the expend arrow near the uninstall button and select install a different version.

Credits for the solution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/724858/vscode-debugger-not-working-for-python.html

Answer (score 0):

Click on the python extention (publisher microsoft) and select "install pre-release". It would be V2022.5.10961002 (you can see it when you hover with the mouse above the extension)

Fixed the problem for me.